# Console log not printing in awaited promise in an async function

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

```js
  function sleep(cb, ms) {
    return new Promise((cb) => setTimeout(cb, ms));
  }

  async function delayedGreeting() {
    console.log("Hello");
    await sleep(myfun, 1000);
    console.log("World!");
  }

  function myfun() {
    console.log("whatever");
  }

  delayedGreeting();
  console.log("Goodbye!");
```

Can someone please explain in the context of Eventloop, Callback Queue and Stack as to what is happening here as I don't see the word 'whatever' in the output. Is there a mistake in the code and if so what is it?

Comment: Please add *javascript* tag to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some minor mistakes in the code. I am pointing them below.

1. You should write resolve in the Promise.

```
return new Promise((resolve) => resolve (setTimeout(()=>{cb()}, ms)));
```

2. If you want `myfun` to run after a timeout of 1000 millisecond, you must call  the function in the settimeout first parameter. Like this,

```
setTimeout(()=>{cb()}, ms);
```

Here is the updated source code,

```js
      function sleep(cb, ms) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => resolve (setTimeout(()=>{cb()}, ms)));
      }

      async function delayedGreeting() {
        console.log("Hello");
        await sleep(myfun, 1000);
        console.log("World!");
      }

      function myfun() {
        console.log("whatever");
      }

      delayedGreeting();
      console.log("Goodbye!");
```

And the right output according to the implementation that you are trying the code should be like this,

```
Hello
Goodbye!
World!
whatever
```

Comment: may I know why is `Goodbye!`  printed before `World!` ?

Comment: because of the await.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add parenthesis for `myfun` function parameter on this line `await sleep(myfun, 1000);`.

**DEMO**

```js
  function sleep(cb, ms) {
    return new Promise((cb) => setTimeout(cb, ms));
  }

  async function delayedGreeting() {
    console.log("Hello");
    await sleep(myfun(), 1000);
    console.log("World!");
  }

  function myfun() {
    console.log("whatever");
  }

  delayedGreeting();
  console.log("Goodbye!");
```

Comment: `myfun()` will execute the function before 1000 millisecond timeout, which is wrong. Instead of there, the parenthesis should be in the `cb()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this -

```
function sleep(cb, ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => resolve(setTimeout(cb, ms)));

  }
```

It seems you are overriding the cb value inside promise.